# UiPath Invoke VBA activity does not use FitToPagesWide properly

Tags: excel, vba, uipath

I am trying to export Excel sheets as PDF using VBA code in `Invoke VBA` activity in UiPath studio.

```vb
Sub SetSheetSize()
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws.PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With
    Next

    Dim saveLocation As String
    saveLocation = "C:\Users\Documents\test.pdf"

    'Save active workbook as PDF
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=saveLocation

    End Sub
```

But the `.FitToPagesWide = 1` does not seem to work. The export to PDF is working fine. When I try to run the exact same vba code as a macro in excel file itself, it gives proper result, but the invoke vba is not scaling the page as per `.FitToPagesWide`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Not fixing you issue in your `Invoke VBA`. But maybe this is even better for you.

My idea would be that you put the code into a public macro in the Excel file. And then you just execute the Macro name via UiPath.

1. Create `Excel application scope`
2. Drag into `Execute macro` activity
3. Set `MacroName` and `MacroParameters`

For more, see [here](https://excelcult.com/how-to-execute-macro-in-uipath/).